How do I generate and publish maven-metadata.xml at the G (group) level for a custom Maven plugin
I've created a custom maven plugin and I've published it to the central maven repository using the org.sonatype.central:central-publishing-maven-plugin plugin.
I run the mvn deploy command to execute the deployment. The plugin is deployed and published successfully but I don't see the maven-metadata.xml file created for the plugin at the group (G) level. https://maven.apache.org/repositories/metadata.html#the-g-level-metadata
I've confirmed my custom maven plugin is configured to use the maven-plugin packaging type. I'm using Maven 3.9.6.
When I run mvn install I can see it is successfully creating/updating a maven-metadata-local.xml file in my local repository as expected.
In terms of having this file created for the central repository, I'm trying to understand if I've misconfigured my project or if there is a bug or functionality missing from central-publishing-maven-plugin.
How does the maven-metadata.xml file get created and published at the group (G) level for plugins for the central repository?

You need ask sonatype about help ... central-publishing-maven-plugin does something by own way ...

This is the response I got from the Sonatype central team:
"the maven-metadata is generated at the server side and uploaded to repo1.maven.org in the process. It looks like there is a bug in the implementation on our side that prevents group level metadata from being created for maven plugins. I opened an internal ticket to investigate and address the issue".
